# How to pass List of parameters to controllers while using grid's sorting and paging?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

It seems that the kendo ui only suppert to pass the parameter like string,int ,but not List this custom class.

```
 ActionResult GetStudentImfo([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string name, int id)
```

this format is OK,but
        `ActionResult GetStudentImfo([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,List<student> para)`

is not OK. It says para is Null.

Comment: What does the query string look like? I suspect this has everything to do with ASP.NET MVC parameter mapping and nothing to do with Kendo.

Comment: query string like this: para.push({"name":"Lyly","id":1});